# pass values between visualforce page salesforce

Tags: visualforce

I have Custom Visual force page MyPage1   and  on click of a button , I am calling /Apex/MyPage2  and also I am passing some input parameters as part of '/apex/MyPage2?accname={!Account.Name}&accid={!Account.Id}';

I am performing some activity in MyPAge2

and at the end, I want to returb back  FinalVariable  back to MyPage1

how I can pass back the response to calling VF page (MyPage1)?

please help

Comment: Any help here plz ?!

Answer (score 0):

Communication between pages can be achieved using Javascript :
   Listener() function in parent page.
    Postmessage() function in chile page